# Bounded algebras of finite global dimension

Tags: homological-algebra, quivers

Let $k$ be a field, $Q$ an acyclic finite quiver and $I$ an admissible ideal of $kQ$.
I am looking for a reference for the fact that the bounded algebra $kQ/I$ has finite global dimension.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is written out in the following note:

http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sek/select/Acyclic.pdf